# Gcloud Datastore runQuery with .order returns error 412 'Precondition Failed'

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing an app with Google Cloud platform Datastore on Node JS. Using a part of the code from Book Shelf example.

The problem that when I'm using .order() in runQuery method with .filter() returns error with code 412 - 'Precondition Failed'. When I do that either without .order() or .filter() works fine. What do I do wrong?

In the code below: list() works; readByQuery() does not.

```
function list(limit, token, cb) {
    var q = ds.createQuery(namespace, kind)
        .limit(limit)
        .order(config.order)
        .start(token);

    ds.runQuery(q, function (err, entities, cursor) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        var hasMore = entities.length === limit ? cursor : false;
        cb(null, entities.map(fromDatastore), hasMore);
    });
}

function readByQuery(key, operator, value, limit, token, cb) {
    var q = ds.createQuery(namespace, kind)
        .filter(key+ ' ' + operator, value)
        .order(config.order)
        .limit(limit)
        .start(token);

    ds.runQuery(q, function (err, entities) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, entities.map(fromDatastore));
    });
}
```

Method readByQuery() returns:

```
[ApiError: Precondition Failed]
    errors: [],
    code: 412,
    message: 'Precondition Failed'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a typical datastore limitation, well documented e.g at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries :

> Note: Because of the way the App Engine Datastore executes queries, if a query specifies inequality filters on a property and sort orders on other properties, the property used in the inequality filters must be ordered before the other properties.

So the `key`, `operator`, and `config.order` strongly constrain each other: specifically, if the operator is an inequality, then `config.order` and `key` *must* be identical -- and nothing in your code checks that.

Comment: Thanks Alex, it is well documented, I need to spend more time reading next time :) However, I still cannot understand how I can get the data, order it and limit to 10, for example. The kind is 'ActivityLog' with userID field. How could I get last 10 activities (ordered by -timestamp) for userId = 123?

Comment: filter for userId *equal* to 123, and order by -timestamp -- no contradiction there. Your readByQuery is just too general -- it will work for some combinations of arguments (e.g, `filter("userId =", 123)` since that's not an *inequality*) and not for others. And you don't show us exactly how you're calling it in the failing case (a crucial bit of the puzzle!).

Comment: All fixed now. And agreed, it's too general, but it didn't work for the failing case "userId equal to 123, and order by -timestamp". I have tried to run the filter followed by clicking onto 'timestamp' field to order in Web Datastore Console (console.developers.google.com/datastore). It showed an error "Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query." I followed steps at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31928803/5735196 and it's fixed now. Don't know is it a bug or maybe I don't fully understand how the Datastore works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah -- missing composite index, I should have thought about that -- sorry, I'll claim the after-effects of the Cenone di San Silvestro (a very traditional Italian feast, and, I've found a restaurant in Silicon Vally serving it properly, and spent the evening of Dec 31 there with my wife and friends) for my mental lapse. I wish that 412 error could be given a separate, more explanatory body for "missing required index" vs "inequality vs order clash", but, it IS really hard... sorry!